# Linking a textbox to a javascript object property

Tags: jquery

I have a dozen text boxes in a web page that I wish to 'bind' to the properties of a javascript object. So - when you update the textbox, the object changes and vice versa.

The other day I thought I stumbled across a jquery library that did this - however, for neither love or money, I can't find it today!

Can someone please point me in the direction of best practise?

Thanks very much in advance.

Z

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're thinking of the [jQuery data link plugin](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/data-link/).

Comment: Just found this accidentally: http://roderick.dk/blog/2010/11/03/jquery-data-link-considered-harmful/

Comment: Thanks very much for that - exactly what I was after. I read the other article as well and it's very interesting. 

Cheers :-)